# Copy header when merging multiple MRI images using nibabel

Tags: python, image-processing, nifti

I have received multiple Nifti-Images of a single fMRI session, where each volume scan has been saved into a single 3D-Nifti-file. These where named, say, 'foobar_001.nii', ..., 'foobar_187.nii'. I want to merge those and have written the following for-loop to do so.

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as ni

def merge_nii_files (sfile, ns):
    # This will load the first image for header information
    img = ni.load(sfile % (3, ns[0]))
    dshape = list(img.shape)
    dshape.append(len(ns))
    data = np.empty(dshape, dtype=img.get_data_dtype())

    header = img.header
    equal_header_test = True

    # Now load all the rest of the images
    for n, i in enumerate(ns):
        img = ni.load(sfile % (3,i))
        equal_header_test = equal_header_test and img.header == header
        data[...,n] = np.array(img.dataobj)

    imgs = ni.Nifti1Image(data, img.affine, header=header)
    if not equal_header_test:
        print("WARNING: Not all headers were equal!")
    return(imgs)

nii_files = "example_%0*d.nii"
images = merge_nii_files(nii_files, range(1,187))
```

As you can see, I would like to make sure that the header information are copied, too. My question: Is this 'header=header' really enough? I am asking because imgs has a 4-tuple shape, but the header I am using comes from a 3-tuple shape. I am not too familiar with the internals of nibabel or the Nifti file format. Did I miss anything, i.e., do I need to copy anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I did not miss anything. The above works.

Comment: I'm not certain the above works in all cases... I'm converting from nifti pair 3D files, and I don't end up with correct TR and (I think) scaling is off from one timepoint to the next.

Comment: For completeness, nibabel has a function `nib.concat_images(fnames)` that will merge 3D volumes into a timeseries properly.

Comment: If `header['pixdim'][4]` is given in the individual images, this will be set equal to the TR in the merged image. So, I have merged my files using `ni.concat_images()` and compared it to my old files and, as the above code does the same thing, got the same result either way. But nevertheless, thank you for pointing me to this function.

Comment: Thank you for checking further!